# Open categories in modal window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've trying to make different categories on the page and when user click on some category must load all images from that category on the modal window which will open.

So far I successfully loaded only categories but can't figured out how to load images on the modal window.
This is the code that I have so far. May be is totally wrong so I need some help here. Currently modal is empty when is opened

```
<?php
 require_once 'misc/database.php';
 $pdo = Database::connect();
 echo '<section id="portfolio" class="grid">';
    foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM albums ORDER BY album_id") as $row) 
    {
        echo '<figure class="effect-portfolio wow fadeIn">
                 <img src="'.$row['album_image'].'" alt="03_img"/>
                 <figcaption>
                    <h2>'.$row['album_name'].'</h2>
                    <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"></a>
                 </figcaption>
              </figure>';
    }
    echo '</section>
           <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
               <div class="lr">
                  <div class="rl">
                  </div>
               </div>
             </div>';
   if(isset($_GET['album_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['album_id'])){
                $album_id = $_GET['album_id'];          
   $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_album = $album_id ORDER BY image_id DESC ");
      foreach ($query as $row) {                                 
         echo '<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="item active">
                              <img src="gallery/'.$row['image_name'].'" alt="...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </div>';
      }      
   }
   echo '</div></div> ';
   Database::disconnect();       
?>
```

May be I see where is the problem but don't see how to fix it. In `<a href="#portfolioModal2">` I should pass the `album_id` but how to make it exactly?